# data returns undefined right before it´s get´s the data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native

I don't really know how to ask this question, but my problem is that the data the header needs return undefined right before it´s get´s the data. So therefore it's crashed even that i get the data, how do i solve this problem ?

```
componentWillMount () {
   this.props.fetchProfileData()
}

<Header
  style={{ padding: 0 }}
  backgroundColor='#1E1E1E'
  outerContainerStyles={{ height: 80 }}
  leftComponent={
    <Avatar
     small
     rounded
     source={console.log(this.props.profile[0])}
     //onPress={this.toggleModal.bind(this)}
    />
   }
   centerComponent={{ text: 'People Out Tonight ', style: { color: '#fff', fontFamily: 'GeosansLight', fontSize: 15 } }}
   rightComponent={{ icon: 'forum', color: '#fff' }}
/>
```

[image]

Comment: what's the error message? why is your `source` `console.log`?

Comment: the error is "cannot find this.props.profile[0] ", i just console it so i can show you that it gets the data but not the first time it´s rendered...

Comment: I guess that you get these data by doing a network request. Please add that code, especially the code in `fetchProfileData()`. Because network request are asynchronous you do not have the data on your first render...

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the error? Which component and line is giving it? What is `this.props.profile` before `fetchProfileData` is completed?

Comment: componentDidMount will be fine.

Comment: @BhojendraNepal This will not fix OPs issue that he does not have the required data on his first render. He will need some kind of conditional rendering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. if `fetchProfileData` is async than I strongly recommend you pass a default value for `profile` either by : `source={this.props.profile[0]||{}}` or by defining default props using [React PropTypes](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html)
2. if you don't want the component to render with empty props the add it to the DOM only when `fetchProfileData` is completed or something like:`render(){return({this.props.profile[0] && <Header ...>});}`